# Why does react quill mentions not showing?

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

I have created a component for RichText with ReactQuill and i am implementing mentions but when i type @ in textbox mentions not working i tried puting dependency in useMemo but the textbox disapears

How can i make this code work so when i type @ it shows the list of people?

Below please find the code which i made

```
const RichText = (props) => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  const reactQuillRef = React.useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
setPeople(props.getPeople)

  }, []);

  const modules = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toolbar: [
        [{ font: [] }],
        [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }],
        ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
        [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
        [{ align: [] }],
        [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
        ["image"],
        ["clean"],
      ],
      mention: {
        allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
        mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
        spaceAfterInsert: true,
        source: (searchTerm, renderList, mentionChar) => {
          let values;

          if (mentionChar === "@") {
            values = people;
          }
          if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
            renderList(values, searchTerm);
          } else {
            const matches = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
              if (
                ~values[i].value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              )
                matches.push(values[i]);
            renderList(matches, searchTerm);
          }
        },
      },
    }),
    []
  );
    
  return (
      <ReactQuill
        defaultValue={props.defaultValue || ""}
        value={props.value || ""}
        theme="snow"
        ref={reactQuillRef}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        className={`note_input`}
        formats={formats}
        modules={modules}
        onChange={(content, delta, source, editor) => {
          props.setValue(content, delta, source, editor);
        }}
      />
  );
};

export default RichText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by these actions:

- Moved people state to parent
- Removed useMemo from mentions
- Added useCallback to source
- Added memo to RichText export

Now everything working as it should.
Below code how it is solved.

```
const RichText = (props) => {
  const reactQuillRef = React.useRef(null);

const modules = {
    toolbar: [
      [{ font: [] }],
      [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }],
      ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
      [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
      [{ align: [] }],
      [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
      ["image"],
      ["clean"],
    ],
    mention: {
      allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
      mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
      spaceAfterInsert: true,
      source: useCallback((searchTerm, renderList, mentionChar) => {
        let values;
        if (mentionChar === "@") {
          values = props.people;
        }
        if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
          renderList(values, searchTerm);
        } else {
          const matches = [];
          console.log("val", values);
          for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            if (
              ~values[i].value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            )
              matches.push(values[i]);
          renderList(matches, searchTerm);
        }
      }, []),
    },
  };
    
  return (
      <ReactQuill
        defaultValue={props.defaultValue || ""}
        value={props.value || ""}
        theme="snow"
        ref={reactQuillRef}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        className={`note_input`}
        formats={formats}
        modules={modules}
        onChange={(content, delta, source, editor) => {
          props.setValue(content, delta, source, editor);
        }}
      />
  );
};

export default React.memo(RichText);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, this helped me! I ended up needing to wrap source in `useCallback` like you did, it seems like the editor gets sad when that isn't referentially stable!